# Horizontal Table needed centering

Tags: css

Bit new at CSS and been looking around at various sites and bits of code trying to get a centered drop down menu which I managed to get :).

However as soon as I added some images to make up the heading the menu shifted off to the left and I have not been able to budge it ever since, any help? Code is below.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-image: url();
    background-color: #0099FF;
}
.style1 {color: #FFCC00}
.style2 {color: #FF9900}
.style3 {
    color: #FFCC00;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.style4 {
    color: #000099;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style5 {color: #000099; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; }
.style6 {color: #000099}
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        body { padding: 5px; }
        ul { list-style: none; margin: auto}
        ul li { float: left; padding-right: 0px; position: relative; }
        ul a { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; height: 50px; text-align: center; background-color: #0099EE; color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border: 1px solid #000000;}
        ul a:hover { background-color: #0066FF; }
        li > ul { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 100%; }
        li:hover > ul { display: inline; }
        li > ul li { padding: 0; padding-top: 0px; }
        #menu-outer {
    height: 84px;
    background: url(images/bar-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


ul#horizontal-list {
    min-width: 696px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    }
    ul#horizontal-list li {
        display:inline
    }


-->
</style></head>

<body>  

  <div id="menu-outer"></div>
<div class="table"></div>
<div align="center"><img src="logo_with_words_3.jpg" width="172" height="145"><img src="heading.gif" width="557" height="69"><img src="logo_with_words_3.jpg" width="172" height="145">
</div>
<ul id="horizontal-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Guest Comments</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Accommodation</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bedrooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">St Joseph's Annexe</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Visiting St Katharine's</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Retreats</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B&B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Conferences</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Find Us</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li><a href="#">Walled Garden</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sue Ryder Legacy</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sue Ryder</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prayer Fellowship</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LRWMT</a></li>

        </ul>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: there is none there, I used a div because a table would not allow drop downs. But should of worded the heading better, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't really using a table, but you can add something like this: `#horizontal-list {margin: auto; width: 850px;}`

[JS Fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/29KdB/)

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it, been trying what I could for a few days now